# Why Won't Ninject New Up Objects In A Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, ninject

```
My Setup:
Visual Studio 2013
Web Forms/MVC project
C#
Ninject 3.2.0.0
Entity Framework
```

I have a Web Forms/MVC hybrid project that uses Ninject for its IoC containter. I've no problems with Ninject until today. The problem I ran into is that I can't get Ninject to new up some objects whenever I use a class. Here is some code that works:

```
// Master1.master
namespace TestCode
{
    public partial class Master1 : MasterPage
    {
        [Inject]
        public FooController Foo { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Do some setup logic.
            Foo.Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is some code that doesn't work using a class:

```
// Master1.master
namespace TestCode
{
    public partial class Master1 : MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Wrapper().SomeMethod();
        }
    }
}

// Wrapper.cs
namespace TestCode
{
    public class Wrapper
    {
        [Inject]
        public FooController Foo { get; set; }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            // Do some setup logic.
            Foo.Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I execute SomeMethod(), Foo is null. Why is this and what can I do to get Ninject to new up Foo?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to use Ninject to give you your object. Just calling `new` won't do any injection because Ninject never ran and nothing told Ninject to run and inject.

Comment: You'd need to get your Wrapper class from the ninject kernel, not new it up. Keyword `new` is a good indication that you've strayed from the DI path. Ninject does not magically override the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - I got it working now. Thanks everyone! I needed to add a binding my NinjectWebCommon class like so:

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        Bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        Bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();


        // Needed to add this binding.
        kernel.Bind<IWraper>().To<Wraper>().InRequestScope();


        RegisterServices(kernel);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
}
```